# I have a DLC item in my inventory, but don't own the DLC?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I have a DLC item in my inventory even though I didn't buy the DLC. It's the Frozen Flower, which is part of the Crown of the Ivory King DLC. If anyone has an explanation on this, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: You're absolutely sure you don't have the DLC? What version of the game did you buy (Dark Souls 2, or Dark Souls 2 Scholar of the First Sin)?

Comment: I bought Dark souls 2 Scholar of the First Sin, but I was sure that a DLC doesn't come with it. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Dark Souls 2 Wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/dark+souls+ii+scholar+of+the+first+sin) and [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/335300/), Dark Souls 2 Scholar of the First Sin contains all the DLC that have been released since April 1st 2015 (the games release date).

Steam words it as:

> DARK SOULS™ II: Scholar of the First Sin includes all the DARK SOULS™ II content released to-date in one package and much more!

The [Frozen Flower](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Frozen+Flower) is automatically given to the player who has the DLC for it.  Since you have the Scholar of the First Sin edition, you do in fact have the DLC (and the rest of the DLCs).  The DLCs are likely not a separate download since this is an enhanced version of Dark Souls 2, and are probably just included with the game download.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea. And here I was waiting until I can buy the DLCs. Thanks a lot. It was one good information and two a real money saver.

Comment: Sure thing. Prepare to die all over again!